# How to check whats there after unzipiping a tar file

Tags: python, tar, unzip

So, Im writing a python script which will open a tar file and if there is a directory in it, my script will open that directory and check for files...

```
E = raw_input("Enter the tar file name: ") // This will take input from the user
tf = tarfile.open(E) // this will open the tar file
```

Now whats the best way to check it 'tf' is having directory or not ? Rather then going my terminal and doing ls there I want do something in the same python script that checks if there is a directory after unzipping the tar.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can check to see if paths exist by using the os.path.exists(f) command, where f is a string representation of the filename and its path:

```
import os

path = 'path/filename'

if os.path.exists(path):
    print('it exists')
```

EDIT:

The tarfile object has a method "getnames()" which gives the paths of all the objects in the tar file.

```
paths = tf.getnames() #returns list of pathnames
f = paths[1] #say the 2nd element in the list is the file you want

tf.extractfile(f)
```

Say there's a file named *"file1"* in directory *"S3"*. Then one of the elements of tf.getnames() will be *'S3/file1'*. Then you can extract it.

Comment: but Im opening a tar file and I want to check if there is anything in it. Suppose I opened a tar file and it gets me a directory "S3". I want open 'S3'. How can I do it in my Python Script

Comment: tf.getnames() gives the paths of all the files inside the tar object and then you can extract them with extractfile()